# Add a "Co-Founder (Former)" label

Tags: feature-request, user-labels

The [blog](https://stackoverflow.blog/) is showing a clear label for authors who are former co-founders of Stack Exchange:

[image: label for former co-founder Jeff Atwood]

[Why is Jeff Atwood's title "Co-Founder (Former)" on The Overflow?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345953/)

Can the same be applied on SE sites now that we have labels for moderators, staff, and even bots?

My idea is something like this:

[image: Jeff Atwood profile with new label sketch]

Comment: By that analogy you would also have to apply this to former staff members. I don't know if they would want such a thing, as that would put some form of weight on their current posts.

Comment: @Luuklag not really, still using blog as reference, the blog has no such indication. Showing if a user is former staff is relevant only in few cases, e.g. when the name appears in the users who closed/deleted a post, so maybe show only there.

Comment: tbh "Co-Founder (Former)" Indicates its suddenly no longer a co-founder...

Comment: I think a better solution would be some way to tag posts by former staff as canonical.

Comment: I believe there was a comment or post from a staff member saying that they were planning to add something like a label indicating someone was a former staff member.

Comment: @CaveJohnson this one? [We need a "former staff" account flag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/347859/346823)

Comment: @LShaver yea I think that was it

Answer (score 4):

I would argue this gives some weight to historical posts and properly puts them into context. The highlighting would be coherent with current usage of Labels.

One interesting approach would be to show Labels retroactively on posts made during the staff members tenure but not beyond. But show the Label in the profile permanently.

Comment: This seems like it would be better to use an [answer label](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/368763/273494) like “staff-post” instead of a label on the user profile. That way it would be easy to distinguish posts made before or after their period of employment from those made during for any former staff member.

Comment: @ColleenV You mean like the "official post banners"? That's an interesting alternative,  but the banners take up more space and carry a sort of weight the that isn't always warranted. I think the labels are overall more inconspicuous. Oh, that post you linked says about using separate staff tags? Well that's already in use with the red tags isn't it?

Comment: No, I mean like an answer label as described in the link in my comment. They’re like question tags, but for answers. They would let us, for example, search for answers posted by staff with certain keywords.

Comment: @ColleenV answer tags, now that's a concept.

Comment: That's not much different from [recommended answers, from Recognized Members](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4gmZh.png); which is already coded for.